# Building executables from open-source library for portability (Festival TTS)

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, makefile, festival

I'm working on a Python/C++ application that will run on Mac OS and relies on the [Festival Speech Synthesis System](https://github.com/festvox/festival), which I'm building from source [here](http://festvox.org/packed/festival/2.5/). In my project, I use Festival's shell-based API (i.e. calling compiled executables from within my app to perform tasks). I'm having issues compiling a portable build of Festival that I can ship around to other (Mac OS) machines. My issue is specifically with absolute paths; I can compile successfully with `./configure` then `make`, but the resulting executables reference absolute paths on my system. Obviously transferring or shipping this build to other machines results in errors since those paths don't exist.

I'm looking for a way to create portable, standalone executables of Festival (on Mac OS). Is this an issue with how I'm compiling? Is there some default switch I can run at compile time to use relative paths, or would I have to edit the makefiles myself? I notice the top-level Makefile [references a variable `TOP`](https://github.com/festvox/festival/blob/master/Makefile#L40) that gets reused across other make files. It's declared as `TOP=.` but when I search the resulting build, I see that it's resolved to an absolute path on my system.

I'm not very deft with C compilers and I have the feeling I'm missing something obvious, since this must be a common task. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Flite is more or less portable. Festival isn't. You can also check rhvoice probably.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev thanks for the response! I'm using Festival more for text dissection than its speech synthesis capabilities. (I'm extracting syllable durations from a text and using it as a backend for [Phonemizer](https://github.com/bootphon/phonemizer)). Flite appears to have some but not all of those capabilities. Was hoping to get some kind of portable Festival build - don't know if there's a way to hack the makefiles or something like that? Or maybe that's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Well, there are much more modern frontends, python-based for example, are you sure you need festival? I don't get your syllable durations thing, phonemizer just converts text to phonemes, why do you need a syllable lenght

Comment: Thanks - agreed there are much more modern tools. By syllable durations I meant one of Festival's utterance features, e.g. `(utt.features utt1 'Syllable '(pos_in_word syl_vowel syllable_duration))`. The phonemizer usage is a separate piece of functionality and I'm sure I could find a replacement for that. Unfortunately my project is pretty tied to the values that come back from `syllable_duration` though. Thanks for your help!